# Search Excel workbook tabs for all entries which match a criteria and produce a list?

Tags: vba, excel

I have  large spreadsheet with over 20+ tabs. each tab has the same structure

```
A=ref,B= Discipline, C=Location, D=item/location, E=Defect, F=Date, G=%complete
```

What i want to do is get the search for G column throughout the entire workbook and return a list of all items which are not listed "100". The result would appear on the summary page.

Over time the list of items would become smaller as more 100 are entered in to the G column.

Could you advise on how I could do this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm sure a search for "looping through sheets" would give you a starting point. It is good if you can show that you have done some work/research into your problem before asking for help.

Comment: i'll try searchiing for that. I've tried looking at Vlookup and a few different VBA queries that i spotted.

Comment: You can make a pivot table across multiple sheets https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

Comment: What is the unique field or combination of fields that each is determined by? Should the worksheet tab name be included in the list?

Comment: What is the scope of the project (i.e. how many rows in a typical list of incomplete)? A list of 100, 1000 or 10,0000 items would make some solutions more viable than others depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Range.Find method in VBA.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

This assumes there'll always be something in column A and copies column A:G on to a sheet called Summary

```
Sub Find100Percent()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rFoundCell As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim shtSummary As Worksheet

    Set shtSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wrkSht.Name <> shtSummary.Name Then
            With wrkSht.Columns(7)
                Set rFoundCell = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
                    sFirstAddress = rFoundCell.Address
                    Do
                        rFoundCell.Offset(, -6).Resize(, 7).Copy _
                            shtSummary.Cells(shtSummary.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)
                    Loop While Not rFoundCell Is Nothing And rFoundCell.Address <> sFirstAddress
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```